# ImportError: Module use of python34.dll conflicts with this version of Python

Tags: python, django

I have downloaded and installed Anaconda3-4.4.0 with Python 3.6. I already have Python 3.4 as the working version.Now after installing, when I try to launch Anaconda prompt I am getting the below error:
[No Module named 'conda'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALn6r.png)

I have also added the path in the environment variables. 
Can anyone provide any suggestion on how to proceed further and solve this issue ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your PYTHONPATH may not be properly set. Check it with:

```
python
...
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

When you were installing Anaconda, you missed a section, When conda asked you if it can set your .bashrc file, you might have clicked NO. It's a simple fix: open your interpreter and add this line:

```
export PATH=/home/add your username here/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Now type python into the interpreter and you will see Anaconda 3-4.4.0 or whatever version you have.

Comment: I am afraid, conda did not ask to set any .bashrc file and I am Windows user. How to proceed ? and also there is no bin folder

Comment: @AshwinKm In windows, before using python, you needed to set python path in my computer's advanced environment setting. Add this path there.

Comment: Yeah I have already set python path and was using without any problem. But when I try to use conda after installing Anaconda, there was an issue. Also I was not able to launch Anaconda Navigator.

Comment: @AshwinKm You need to add this **anaconda3** path also there.

Comment: @AshwinKm From where did you install Anaconda into Windows?? It always asks for Python path related settings. See here https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows.html

Comment: Yeah I downloaded it from the official website only. I also added the path. Check out this  [https://imgur.com/a/KJPnd]

Comment: @AshwinKm also, activate your working environment. Might be a problem there.

Comment: Can you explain how to activate the working environment ? I am not sure